# arcpy fails to get spatial reference in hydro script

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, arcgis-pro, hydrology, hydrology-toolset

I have an ArcPy script that extracts a stream network from any chunk of terrain.  It takes the terrain and if it's in a GCS, it projects it to the correct UTM zone prior to further processing.  Though the projection is accomplished successfully, it's failing to successfully perform the fill sink operation.  Here is the code in question.

```
out_raster = r"in_memory\utm_{}".format(utm_grid_name)
utm_projected_terrain = arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(dted, out_raster, projection_string)
arcpy.AddMessage('Done reprojecting raster.')

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#do the fill
outfill = Fill(utm_projected_terrain)
arcpy.AddMessage('Done with fill sinks')
```

I keep this in memory because this workstation has 128gb RAM, it's more efficient and quicker to perform the analysis here.  The terrain file size is anywhere from around 35-100mb.

Here is the error I'm getting; strangely it seems to do with Spatial Reference:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File"C:\Temp\PyCharmProjects\Hydro\stream-network-extractor.py", line 81, in <module>
    outfill = Fill(utm_projected_terrain)
  File "c:\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 2307, in Fill
    z_limit)
  File "c:\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 2303 in Wrapper
    z_limit)
  File c:\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 496, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail.  Please refer to the error help for potential solutions, or contact Esri Technical Support http://esriurl.com/support.
No spatial reference exists.
Failed to execute (Fill).
Failed to execute (StreamOrderExtractor).
```

So this mystifies me because when I run the reprojection script on its own, in the `in_memory` environment, I get a good result, there is a spatial reference, no errors in the output.  Why is `Fill` failing?

Comment: have you tried running the fill on `out_raster` rather than `utm_projected_terrain`? I don't think the management tools write outputs the same way that spatial analyst tools do.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and report back, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Lovette tried running it to `out_raster` and got the same exact error.

Comment: arcpy.Raster is missing.

Comment: @FelixIP cool, so what line is it missing from

Comment: Fill(arcpy.raster(...)))

Comment: @FelixIP - nope, `Fill(arcpy.Raster(utm_projected_terrain))` and `Fill(arcpy.Raster(out_raster))` both fail with the same error.

Comment: The ERROR 999999 should clue you in - this is a generic error, and http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/999001-999999/tool-errors-and-warnings-999998-999999-999999.htm hints to many problems.
Before trying to run the output raster through the Fill tool, first try adding the result of that process as a layer using the make-feature-layer tool. Once the raster is loaded as a layer then try using it in the Fill tool. 
Just because the raster is created in_memory, it is not a layer yet, which would indicate that arcpy can't use it as input in the Fill tool.

Comment: @SorinRUSU thanks; so far it's still failing.  I put in `projected_raster = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(utm_projected_terrain, projected_terrain_name)` (with `projected_terrain_name` using `arcpy.CreateScratchName('utm_')`).  Still giving me the same error.  Again, the projected raster dataset IS getting created successfully, I see it sitting in my project GDB.

Comment: Can you check whether you can manually run the output_raster in any geoprocessing tools, outside the arcpy script? Not just the Fill tool, maybe even a generate hillshade/slope. Just to make sure the arcpy.ProjectRaster_management() is outputing it correctly.
Can you load the raster in ArcGIS Pro/ArcMap and view it correctly?

Comment: @SorinRUSU yes, I can. It completes projection, puts the output in my project GDB, and I can use it in any raster processing tools successfully.  I should note that I am doing all of this in ModelBuilder successfully (with projection being done in its own custom script); I would just like to put it in a python script for greater portability.

Comment: i know it sounds stupid, but try closing the software and/or restarting the computer. ArcGIS has a known issue with locking files/creating locks that then create havok. Also, could you share a sample of the data and script so to test the behavior ourselves?

Comment: @SorinRUSU I do appreciate all the input and I took your suggestion and tried that, but to no avail.  Unless anyone has a definitive answer, I suppose I will set my team up with QGIS, so that they can use the SAGA libraries for hydrology, where I have the script working.  Unfortunately I'm on a closed network and the data is proprietary so I can't post any here. However any publicly available terrain should do.

Comment: I was going to suggest qgis as a viable alternative, and you will also be freed from any licensing fees. Glad to hear the script is working in SAGA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I sorted this out.  It turns out that it had to do with the way I was creating the initial raster.  Even though the script was saying there was a "raster object" as the initial input, and even though the projection generated a correctly referenced raster in standalone mode, I had to integrate the following in my code.  I list it here to close the question because it fixed my problem; perhaps it is a helpful tip to someone else in the future.

Instead of issuing a Spatial Reference *string*, I had to get a Spatial Reference *object*:

```
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference()
sr.factoryCode = epsg # the EPSG code for the correct UTM zone, pulled earlier
sr.create()
```

*Now* I can do:

```
utm_grid_name = arcpy.CreateScratchName("utm_")
utm_projected_terrain = arcpy.ProjectRaster_management(dted, utm_grid_name, sr)
```

And all the algebra works from that point on.

**Lesson learned**: be 100% sure that a valid layer/filetype/dataset is being generated for input.